# String reverse - segfault

Tags: c, string, reverse

This is not a repeated qn. A new method is used to reverse a string from already asked qn.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *revStr(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    char *retStr;

    while(str[count] != '\0')
    {
        printf("first %c for %d\n", str[count], count);
        count++;
    }

    count--;

    for (i = count, j = 0; i >= 0, j<=count; i--, j++)
    {
        //printf("sec %c for %d\n", str[i], i);
        retStr[i] = str[j];
        printf("thrd %c for %d\n", retStr[i], i);
    }
    return retStr;
}

int main()
{
    char *str = NULL, *revStr2 = NULL;
    str = (char *) malloc (5);
    strcpy(str, "hello");
    printf("\n%s\n", str);
    printf("\n%s\n", revStr(str));
}
```

gives me the output as
O/P:

```
hello
first h for 0
first e for 1
first l for 2
first l for 3
first o for 4
thrd h for 4
thrd e for 3
thrd l for 2
thrd l for 1
thrd o for 0
olleh

Segmentation fault
```

Can someone pls help how string reveral can be acheived using this method.
Thanks,
Preethi

Comment: "hello" is six bytes, not five (with null terminator).

Comment: `retStr` has not been initialised before `retStr[i] = str[j];` and there should be a compiler warning about this.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError even after changing malloc into 6 byles, facing the same issue.

Comment: @WeatherVane dint get any warnings am using online compiler

Comment: To see what causes the segmentation fault you should run your program in a debugger until it crashes, then check at which point in the program the problem occurred. Or use a memory checker tool like `valgrind`.

Comment: Using unintialised pointer is a prime candidate for segfault error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to assign memory to retstr like below

```
char *revStr(char *str)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    while(str[count] != '\0')
    {
        printf("first %c for %d\n", str[count], count);
        count++;
    }
 char *retStr = (char*)malloc(count);
    count--;

    for (i = count, j = 0; i >= 0, j<=count; i--, j++)
    {
        //printf("sec %c for %d\n", str[i], i);
        retStr[i] = str[j];
        printf("thrd %c for %d\n", retStr[i], i);
    }
    return retStr;
}
```

Comment: you should andd one byte for final `\0`

Comment: @Mathieu it has the null as i initialized to length +1

Comment: No, `malloc` doesn't initialize the memory pointed by `retStr`. You can use `calloc` or manually set the last byte.